# Lines of a linear subspace are in a variety, the space is in the variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $L\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{N}$ be a linear subspace, $Q\subseteq L$ be an irreducible quadric hypersurface in $L$ and $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{N}$ certain algebraic variety. Let us suppose that for a general $p\in Q$ there exists a line $l_{p}\subseteq L, l_{p}\nsubseteq Q$ such that $p\in l_{p}\subseteq X$. Can we deduce from here that $L\subseteq X$? In case we don't, are there any extra condition that we could add for it to be true?

I think it must have something to do with the fact that 
$$
\langle Q\rangle=L,
$$
but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Let $Y$ be set $\{t \in L, \exists p \in Q, t \in l_p \}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ be the Zariski closure of $Y$ in $L$. Then, by your assumption, two things are clear:

_ the variety $\tilde{Y}$ is equal to $L$,

_the set $Y$ is included in $X$, hence $\tilde{Y}$ is included in $X$.

Comment: @Libli Excuse me, how do we know that $\overset{\sim}{Y}=L$? Thanks.

Comment: @SrinivasaGranujan Using the incidence variety, you easily show that the dimension of $\tilde{Y}$ is strictly bigger than that of $Q$.